# Pointers Run time error

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic

I have used the below code for a simple operation 
(to reverse a string). But the program is not executing. It gets a run time error (SIGSEGV) . I used a GCC compiler. Please help me in debugging the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *create(int n) {
    int *a;
    a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    return a;
}

void get(int *a, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", *(a + i));
    }
}

void reverse(int *a, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("\n %d", *(a + i));
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, *a;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = create(n);
    get(a, n);
    reverse(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d",*(a+i));` invokes *undefined behavior* because you passed `int` where `int*` is expected.

You must pass pointer to tell `scanf()` where to store the data read, so stop dereferencing and try using `scanf("%d",(a+i));` instead.

More notes are:

- You should check if readings are successful.
- They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).